# Java data structures, a map that uses an object inside the value as the key

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, set

I'm still unsure on how to explain this properly but I will give it my best shot:

I have a set of objects that have values inside that I would like to use as the key for a map.

In order to get the object I'm looking for, I could simply iterate over the set comparing the inner values as I go; this seems inefficient considering one of these values inside the object could be used as a key.
Now the issue is this: were I to change the value inside the object, I also have to update the key to the map, is there not a data structure that would facilitate this task?

In essence; I would like an auto-updating map with keys changing as the value inside changes... I would rather not have to store the map inside the value so, surely there's a more efficient way of thinking than my closed mind?

I hope I've explained myself well enough to get my thinking across.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, consider this code:

```
    public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test test = new Test(5);
            Map<Test, String> map = new HashMap<Test, String>();
            map.put(test, "I'm here");
            test.value = 10;
            System.out.print(map.get(test));
        }

    }

    class Test{
        public int value;
        Test(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

As the object you pass into the map as a key is passed by reference, any changes on the object will be reflected in the key set as well. This way you can use entire object as a key, not just the field it contains. You will need to be careful with providing proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, though.

Comment: But am I right in thinking that this method would also require the creation of Test when I wish to access the map?
Java semantics continue to boggle my mind

Comment: @TFC, quote: `I have a set of objects that have values inside..`. Looks like you already have the objects you want. What I mean is that you can use those objects as keys, not just the values they contain.

Comment: But the objects are the values that I would require...I know the objects name and I need the object in order to get a color, the problem is that the object also needs access to its name.

Comment: @TFC, You can override the equals and hashcode methods on `Test` to allow you compare it with `String`, for example. Otherwise you'll have to create new instances of those and still override equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like an auto-updating map with keys changing as the value inside changes..

Well, you interesting to change parent a.e. storage (`Map`) on any child change (`Value`). I don't know if its good design.

If you change the key to `Value`, `map` doesn't change

So I would write custom `Map` like:

```
 public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Value> {/**/}
```

and there I would override `put` method and implement `onValueChange()` method by using `Interface`.

Each child will store instance of `Map` through `interface`.

So here we go ....:

**RegisterItf**

```
public interface RegisterItf {
   public void onValueChange(String newKey, String oldKey, Value newValue);
}
```

**MyMap**

```
public class MyMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, Value> implements RegisterItf{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Value put(String key, Value value) {
        value.setReg(this); // send map instance to each child who registered
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(String newKey, String oldKey, Value newValue) {
        //here you remove old key and add new one
    }
}
```

**Value**

```
public class Value {
    private String mSomeData;
    private String mKey;

    private RegisterItf reg;


    public void setmKey(String key) {

        if(reg != null){
            reg.onValueChange(key, mKey, this);
        }

        this.mKey = key;
    }

   public void setReg(RegisterItf reg) {
        this.reg = reg;
    }
}
```

**main**

```
       MyMap map = new MyMap();

        Value val = new Value();
        val.setmKey("aa");
        val.setmSomeData("blabla");

        map.put(val.getmKey(), val);
...
```

Comment: If it is not a good design, any ideas on how I would create a better design?

Comment: take a look on classes I added, hope it will help you, good luck